# Add/Update custom field in QuickBook through WebConnector in PHP

Tags: php, soap, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am working on QuickBook Webconnector Integration with Sugar CRM. I have been successfully inserted/Updated the customer record But I am missing some thing in the XML request When I add Custome field In QuickBook.

Here is my XML Request.

```
function _quickbooks_customer_update_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale) {
// Grab the data from our MySQL database
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = " . (int) $ID));

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerModRq>
                <CustomerMod>
                    <ListID>' . $arr['ListID'] . '</ListID>
                    <EditSequence>' . $arr['EditSequence'] . '</EditSequence>
                    <Name>' . $arr['Name'] . '</Name>
                    <CompanyName>' . $arr['Name'] . '</CompanyName>
                    <FirstName>' . $arr['FirstName'] . '</FirstName>
                    <LastName>' . $arr['LastName'] . '</LastName>

                    <BillAddress>                                       <!-- opt -->
                        <Addr1>' . $arr['Addr1'] . '</Addr1>                            <!-- opt, max length = 41 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 500 for QBOE -->
                        <Addr2>' . $arr['Addr2'] . '</Addr2>                            <!-- opt, max length = 41 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 500 for QBOE -->
                        <City>' . $arr['City'] . '</City>                              <!-- opt, max length = 31 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                        <State>' . $arr['State'] . '</State>                            <!-- opt, max length = 21 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                        <PostalCode>' . $arr['PostalCode'] . '</PostalCode>                  <!-- opt, max length = 13 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 30 for QBOE -->
                        <Country>' . $arr['Country'] . '</Country>                        <!-- opt, max length = 31 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                    </BillAddress>

                    <ShipAddress>                                       <!-- opt -->
                        <Addr1>' . $arr['Addr1'] . '</Addr1>                            <!-- opt, max length = 41 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 500 for QBOE -->
                        <Addr2>' . $arr['Addr2'] . '</Addr2>                            <!-- opt, max length = 41 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 500 for QBOE -->
                        <City>' . $arr['City'] . '</City>                              <!-- opt, max length = 31 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                        <State>' . $arr['State'] . '</State>                            <!-- opt, max length = 21 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                        <PostalCode>' . $arr['PostalCode'] . '</PostalCode>                  <!-- opt, max length = 13 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 30 for QBOE -->
                        <Country>' . $arr['Country'] . '</Country>                        <!-- opt, max length = 31 for QBD|QBCA|QBUK|QBAU, max length = 255 for QBOE -->
                    </ShipAddress>
                    <Phone>' . $arr['Phone'] . '</Phone>                              <!-- opt, max length = 21 -->
                    <Fax>' . $arr['Fax'] . '</Fax>                                  <!-- opt, max length = 21 -->
                    <Email>' . $arr['Email'] . '</Email>
                </CustomerMod>
            </CustomerModRq>
                <DataExtModRq>
                    <DataExtMod>
                        <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                        <DataExtName>SugarCRMId</DataExtName>
                        <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
                        <ListObjRef>
                                <FullName>' . $arr['Name'] . '</FullName>
                        </ListObjRef>
                        <DataExtValue>52</DataExtValue>
                    </DataExtMod>
                </DataExtModRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
    return $xml;
}
```

This Request Execute withoput generating Error But did not add value in the custom field of QuickBook.

Custom field name is **"SugarCRMId"** and its kid of data is Any text.

Please guide me if you understand this issue.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the full XML request you send to QuickBooks, and the full XML response you got back from QuickBooks. No one can help you unless you show us what you're sending, and what you got back.

Comment: Thank you sir for your considration. Now I put the whole function defination. Please see again and help me. Thanks

Comment: That's not helpful. We need to see THE REQUEST YOU SENT TO QUICKBOOKS, and THE RESPONSE YOU GOT BACK FROM QUICKBOOKS. Please post the request/response. Look in the quickbooks_log SQL table or the Web Connector log to find this information.